# why is this image not taking when its grabbed the same as the others?

Tags: css

So I have some images in my assets/images folder:
[image]

If you look at my styles.css file:

```
body {
    /*background-color: #F5F4F1;*/
    background-image: url('./img/bg.jpg');
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #353535;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
```

It grabs bg.jpg just fine, but it will not grab hr.png and its coded the same:

```
hr {
    border: none;
    height: 18px;
    width: 114px;
    background-image: url('./img/hr.png') center center no-repeat;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

I do not know why that is and have tried different fixes to no avail.

Comment: check ur console on browser. It might hint you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add `center center no-repeat` to `background-image` (but you can add it to `backgroud`)

**Try this**

CSS

```
hr {
    /* Other */
    background-image: url('./img/hr.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    /* Other */
}
```

or

```
hr {
    /* Other */
    background: url('./img/hr.png') center center no-repeat;
    /* Other */
}
```